# Copy all dependencies from one Gradle configuration to another

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'd like to copy all Gradle dependencies from one configuration to another. Specifically I'd like to copy everything in `compile` to `jmh`.

I have found that I can get this to work with the following:

```
configurations {
    compile.dependencies.each {
        jmh.dependencies.add(it)
    }
}
```

But I'm sure there must be a more elegant or idiomatic way to do this in Gradle. I don't control the creation of the `jmh` configuration: it's created by a plugin. What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's fine to not really copy dependencies, but to refer to them, you could do:

```
dependencies {
    jmh configurations.compile
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly and is definitely cleaner than my version. Thanks! Out of interest, what's the practical difference between copying the dependencies and referring to them?

Comment: Well, your code copies references to dependencies, whereas my code creates a reference to *all* dependencies as a whole. Theoretically, if `compile` dependencies would be programmatically changed after these code snippets, your code would not reflect that as part of `jmh`, whereas my code would.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting.  Thanks for the clarification.